# What is the default file system?

Tags: filesystem, 11.10, ext4

I am presuming that at this late stage in development, the default file system of 11.10 will not change from now until final release. Will it be ext4, and if/when it changes, how will systems on the old format upgrade, in their current state, or changing the entire parition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oneiric is past feature-freeze - there is no chance that the one of the fundamentals such as the file-system will change at this stage.

Given past experience of LTS's - these tend to be very conservative - i.e. incremental change - thus very unlikely to again change file-system - again many [people are speculating about 12.10](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11246451) which could involve major changes such as Wayland.

There was at one time much talk of btrfs being the replacement for ext4.  Btrfs is maturing with time - with support gradually being added - for example - update-manager in oneiric now has [btrfs support](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/foundations-o-update-manager-btrfs).

As to how we would migrate from ext4 to btrfs - there is already support to convert from ext4 to btrfs by installing the package `btrfs-tools`.  This will install `btrfs-convert` which can convert ext4 to btrfs.

Assuming Canonical makes the decision in (for example) 12.10 - expect to see a blue-print which will outline using these packages to provide a smooth migration path.

Answer (score 3):

When I first installed Ubuntu the default file system was ext3. I am now using 11.04 on the same / partition and /home partition and the file system for both partitions is still ext3. An upgrade will not change the file system type.

A new install will change the file system type if you allow it to use the default settings as is proved by a new 11.04 and 11.10 install on two other partitions. The file system on those two partitions is ext4.

It is called being backward compatible.

Regards.